# Is there any HTML 5 framework available to support rapid development?

Tags: html, frameworks, extjs

IS there any HTML 5 framework available for rapid development?

I found [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/), but it is specifically for mobile development.

Comment: Sencha also makes Ext JS for desktop browsers... if you're trying to go both desktop and mobile via the same codebase, Sencha may not be the best choice. Ext JS and Touch target different use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [HTML5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/). It's more of a template than a framework though.
Btw Sencha Touch is built on ExtJS which is a Javascript framework.

Comment: Its looking good, let me check it out. Yup, I saw it is mentioned in its documentation.

Comment: Hey it is mentioned that BoilerPlate is delete key friendly----- What is that?

Comment: I suspect it is because there are quite a few things in it that are not strictly necessary for most projects. These can be deleted

Answer (score 1):

(shameless plug) I'm developer of Construct 2, a Windows editor for HTML5 games and apps.  http://www.scirra.com (end shameless plug)

Answer (score 0):

The [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) project is nice for rapid development - you get CSS files for the grid layout, nice typography and forms and basic page elements like buttons, navigation, menus, alerts, pagination. You also get JavaScripts for functionality like Dropdown menus, Modal dialogs, Tooltips, Tabs, Alerts, Buttons, Typeahead.